# How to create boxplot based on 5 year intervals in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, boxplot

I have a continuous variable y measured on different dates. I need to make boxplots with a box showing the distribution of y for each 5 year interval.

Sample data:

```
rdob <- as.Date(dob, format= "%m/%d/%y")
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=rdob, y=ageyear)) + geom_boxplot()

#Warning message:
#Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)?
```

[image]

This image is the first one I tried. What I want is a box for every five year interval, instead of a box for every year.

Comment: Not totally following what you mean by "Convert date to years". The number of years from a certain time perhaps?

Comment: A simple way is to bin the dates with the cut command: cut(rdob, "5 year"),  This should provide the cuts at "pretty" intervals: ie 1900, 1905, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to pull out the year in base R:

```
format(as.Date("2008-11-03", format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y")
```

Simply wrap your date vector in a `format()` and add the "%Y".  To get this to be integer, you can use `as.integer`.

You could also take a look at the `year` function in the `lubridate` package which will make this extraction a little bit more straightforward.

One method to get 5 year intervals is to use `cut` to create a factor variable that creates levels at selected break points. Unless you have dozens of years your best bet would be to set the break points manually:

```
df$myTimeInterval <- cut(df$years, breaks=c(1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015))
```

Comment: Thank you! I also have a question for the cut function. I tried to run the code you gave, but there is an error called"Error in df$decimaldob : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" Would you mind explaining more ?

Comment: Is your data.frame named df? If yes, you may want to look at what type decimaldob is. You can check this using `str(df)`. then look to see what type the variable is.

Comment: The format command may turn the result into a character/string, if that is the case then the cut command will not work.  Thus the need to wrap the statement in the as.integer statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example taking Dave2e's suggestion of using [cut on date intervals](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.POSIXt.html) along with ggplot's [group aesthetic mapping](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html):

```
library(ggplot2)

n <- 1000

## Randomly sample birth dates and dummy up an effect that trends upward with DOB
dobs <- sample(seq(as.Date('1970/01/01'), Sys.Date(), by="day"), n)
effect <- rnorm(n) + as.numeric(as.POSIXct(dobs)) / as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()))
data <- data.frame(dob=dobs, effect=effect)

## boxplot w/ DOB binned to 5 year intervals
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=dob, y=effect)) + geom_boxplot(aes(group=cut(dob, "5 year")))
```

[image: Boxplot binned by 5 year intervals]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
year=year(rdob)
```