# Aggregate data by year interval inside bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to aggregate data by year interval inside a bar plot. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37333944/7114709), I wrote the following code:

```
years <- seq(as.Date('1970/01/01'), Sys.Date(), by="year")
set.seed(111)
effect <- sample(1:100,length(years),replace=T) 
data <- data.frame(year=years, effect=effect)
ggplot(data, aes(year, effect)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(group=cut(year, "5 years")))
```

[image]
However, only the tick marks are affected, but the data is not summed by interval. Can I get ggplot2 to sum the data without preprocessing the data, while keeping the tick marks and labels as they are?

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'd like to keep the tick marks and labels as they are, i.e. tick marks positioned at the left hand edge of each bar (which now covers 5 years) and year only in the labels. This is based on the appearance of the linked answer above.

Comment: Is this what you are expecting ? `ggplot(data, aes(cut(year, "5 years"))) + geom_bar(aes(weight = effect))`

Comment: Yes, thank you @cderv! but I'm also trying to keep the x tick marks correctly positioned and formatted as the first year of each interval (as in the diagram which I provided).

Comment: It is a good idea to include `set.seed(111)` (with any number as argument) in the beginning of code if some random function is executed. This way others can obtain the exact data that you have.

Comment: How do you want to aggregate data inside bins: with `sum`, `mean` or something else?
Stating the question something like "I want to plot bar for every 5 year interval showing the sum of `effect`" will be more informative for others.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly hacky way of doing what you want:

```
ggplot(data, aes(cut(year, "5 years"), effect)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab("year")
```

[image]

What it actually does: it plots multiple columns (bars) with height equals to `effect` but stacked on top of each other based on 5-year interval identifier. In other words, on plot there are actually 48 bars with one colour but positioned on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(index = ceiling(seq_along(years) / 5)) %>% 
  group_by(index) %>% 
  mutate(sum_effect = sum(effect)) %>% 
  distinct(sum_effect, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, sum_effect)) +
  geom_col()
```

Which returns:

[image]

I prefer transforming the dataset so that I don't have to do anything fancy with `ggplot2`